# Where is CMakefile.txt of colcon?

Tags: ros2, pcl, colcon

I get the same issue in pcl https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2303
which is like below

/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/octree/octree_key.h:155:9: error: ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs [-Werror=pedantic]
155 |         };

the solution they suggested is add include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
However, I do not see CMakefile.txt in build, install or log directory.
How should I solve the issue?
Any advice would be grateful.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding that link.
The *colcon* version of *CMakeFile.txt* is, roughly spoken, the **setup.py**.
But, since you want to define a new message, then you should know, that this option is not available for Python. For this reason you need to create new messages by using C++ as [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Single-Package-Define-And-Use-Interface.html) explained.

In short: you have to create a new package using *ament_cmake*

```
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake <your_package>
```